# Telnet localhost fails to connect (Apache and httpd running normally)

Tags: apache, solaris, httpd.conf

My apache services are working on solaris server. It will be running normally for days but suddenly it hangs. httpd will shown process running but telnet localhost will not connect.

Comment: Please check [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0):

`telnet localhost` will only connect if you are running a local telnet server...I believe Sun started turning that off by default in Solaris 10.

`telnet localhost 80` will try to connect to port 80, where your Apache server might be running.  But many Apache configurations are not set to listen on localhost. Instead, try `telnet XXX 80`, where XXX is the IP number that Apache is listening on. You can see a list of the IP addresses on your current zone with `ifconfig -a`.

If Apache really IS hanging, you are going to need to gather more information, like

- what happens when you telnet into it
- what is the output of `netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep '\*\.80'`
- does it start working again when you HUP the main process (look for the pid which is the parent of all the others)
- what is in the main Apache error_log?

Apache is extremely stable, and if it's hanging, you likely have a either an astable plugin, or somehow you are consuming too many of some resource (like you have a 1000-child limit and 1000 people doing http long poll or something)